# Display Search icon inside search box , throws error in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to add search icon inside search box here's my code so far :

```
 <div className='search'>
            <input
              id="quick_search"
              className="xs-hide"
              name="quick_search"
              placeholder="Search by creator, collectible or collection."
              type="text"
              onChange={(e) => {
                changeKey(e);
              }}
              onKeyDown={keyPress}
              value={keyword} 
              >
             <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>  
              </input>
          </div>
```

i face this Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

can anyone help me with this ? much appreciated !
thanks

Answer (score 2):

React's `input` element the same as HTML's `input` element can't have children.

You have to make the icon appear in the input box using CSS, you can't place it as a child.

```css
.form-field {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-field">
  <input>
  <span class="icon"></span>
</div>
```

Also, you didn't close the `<input>` tag. It's wrong because every tag in react has to be closed either by using the closing tag `</input>` or using a self-closing tag `<input />`

You code should probably look like this:

```
<div className='search'>
  <input
    id="quick_search"
    className="xs-hide"
    name="quick_search"
    placeholder="Search by creator, collectible or collection."
    type="text"
    onChange={(e) => {
      changeKey(e);
    }}
    onKeyDown={keyPress}
    value={keyword}
  /> {/* <--- notice `/` here */}
  <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried this but error was not solved @konrad linkowski

Comment: the icon image is outside the input field and position is not good.

Comment: I just spotted that you didn't close your `input` element

Comment: <div class="form-field">
  <input>
  <span class="icon"></span>
</input>
</div>

If i do this i get same error issue..

Comment: As I said in the answer, `input` cannot have any children

Comment: yeah that way it worked , but display is like this : 

https://im.ge/i/F2Sx9m

is there no way to keep that inside search space ? ._.

Comment: As I said in the answer, you have to use CSS to do this. There is no other way.